# Library not Found

Tags: iphone, ios, clang, ld

Pulling my hair out on this Library not found error after updating to Xcode 5!

```
ld: library not found for -lAppLovinSdk
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried with Library Search Path but no luck.Does any one know how to solve this?

Comment: Just check while adding the framework did you click the add totargets check box and check box of copy files ....

Comment: Yes i have.It was working perfectly fine until i updated to Xcode 5.

Comment: In xcode 5 just remove that file and readd it

Comment: Ahhh.it did the trick for me.Thanks man!